# React Native App dies in a week (initial error)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am developing a react native app. Everything works fine on simulator or on the real phone but if I dont rebuild my app on my phone like for a week, it dies and cannot start. I am sharing a video below to show you whats happening. Any idea why this happens?

If I rebuild the app, it works fine. Please check the link below:

https://youtu.be/GO67Bb6wlog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with react-native, but with Apple. You need to rebuild the app every week with XCode (react-native do it automatically). You can read about this [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/51527).

Comment: As currently being a free developer (in terms of apple liscence) this make sense. I will check it out thanks.